# anchor element creation javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I had created an anchor element using createElement() (in both chrome and firefox developer tools) and when I try to display the element in the console, I find blank. When trying the same with div element creation, I can see the element displayed in console correctly. Below is the actual code and output. What is the reason for this? Should not the anchor element output as a: [object HTMLAnchorElement]?

**Code:**
In the console of chrome developer tool

```
var anchor = document.createElement(‘a’)
console.log(‘anchor: ‘ + anchor)
```

**Output**
a:

**Code:**

```
var div = document.createElement('div')
console.log(‘div: ‘ + div)
```

**Output**
div: [object HTMLDivElement]

Comment: what is with those quotes?

Comment: They are string literals.

Comment: Well the error you would get using them in chrome would be "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anchor is there, you're just using the console incorrectly.

You're concatenating a string with an object, and `anchor.toString()` returns an empty string, while with a DIV it would return `[object HTMLDivElement]`.

To solve it, just use the console correctly, either log them seperately

```
var anchor = document.createElement('a')
console.log('anchor: ')
console.log(anchor)
```

or use a comma as a seperator

```
var anchor = document.createElement('a')
console.log('anchor:', anchor)
```

and you'll log the object as an object, not as a string

Comment: Thanks adeneo for you answer. I also want to understand why the anchor.toString() does not return [object HTMLAnchorElement]. Is there any reference that can clarify this. I was not able to find any.

Comment: @raj - I'm not sure why, you'd think that's exactly what it should return when stringified, but it doesn't, and I couldn't find any references as to why it doesn't?